# How to calculate total sum?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a form and there is a demo here: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/FPgI3Mtowb6qrPZQnF8K

Please note that the form is kept simple so I have not added controls to html.

I have to do some calculations in the form. I have created a subscribe functions which listen to value changes.

My Idea is that when ever point are added then `totalPOintInTournament` and total point is calculated and shown to user.

I am not sure how to do the calculation.

Check my code here:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    Playername: <input formControlName="player" type="text" ><br>
</form>

TotalPoint: 14 <br>
totalPointInTournament: 9 <br>
totalPointInTournament: 5 <br>

<pre>
    {{myForm.value |json}}
</pre>
```

Component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
    FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray,
    ReactiveFormsModule, AbstractControl
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-contact',
    templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

    myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            player: new FormControl(''),
            totalPoint: '14',
            weeks: this.fb.array([
                this.fb.group({
                    totalPointInTournament: '9',
                    matches: this.fb.array([
                        this.fb.group({
                            point: '5'
                        }),
                        this.fb.group({
                            point: '4'
                        })
                    ])
                }),
                this.fb.group({
                    totalPointInTournament: '5',
                    matches: this.fb.array([
                        this.fb.group({
                            point: '3'
                        }),
                        this.fb.group({
                            point: '2'
                        })
                    ])
                })
            ])
        }
        );
        this.updateStats();
    }

    updateStats() {
        this.myForm.get('weeks').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
            // Calculate total point here..
            console.log('val' + JSON.stringify(typeof (val)));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: your points are not numbers they are strings as you wrap them in quotes

Comment: yes but it is not the problem. My problem is that i dont know how to iterate through all the formgroup to make calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all controls within a formGroup. See [this](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#controls).

This is useful for you, you can extract the values like so:

```
const myForm = this.fb.group({...});
Object.values(myForm).forEach(formControl => {
   console.log(formControl.value)
})
```

Your update function would have the give the index to your nested forms to get everything right.